# Motorola ET1 android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am porting an iPad application to the Motorola ET1 andriod tablet. I would like to create the application in Android rather then using RhoMobile suite because our skill set is closer tied to Java then HTML.

Is there an emulator for the Motorola ET1 that will run with the android sdk under elipse?

Answer (score 0):

I you download RhoStudio it inclues an Android emulator where you can test application for ET1.
If that helps...